# How to use where > date in django orm?

Tags: django

How to use where > date in django orm ?

It's work:

```
 res = Prog.objects.filter(end = datetime.now()).order_by('-start')
```

but this not work:

```
 res = Prog.objects.filter(end > datetime.now()).order_by('-start')
```

Why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [`documentation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt):

#### gt

Greater than.

Example:

```
Entry.objects.filter(id__gt=4)
```

SQL equivalent:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id > 4;
```

In your case it would be:

```
res = Prog.objects.filter(end__gt=datetime.now()).order_by('-start')
```